# Symbolical mathematical problem (mathematica)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I got given this question in my tutorial for which I could do parts a) and b). Do you have 
any ideas for part c)?

Question : 
Symbolically solve the following equation for the quantity `r=y/x`:

```
3/y^4==3/x^4+a/(x+2y)^4
```

(a) Use Map or Thread to perform the substitution `y->r x` to both sides of the equation.

```
 ans:    
    3/(r^4 x^4) == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 r x)^4
```

(b)  Plot the solutions for `a\[Element]{-1,1}`. For `a\[Element]{-1,1}`, how many solutions are real valued? Does this number depend on  `a` ?

```
 ans: Graph and 4 solutions and no its doesn't depend on `a`.
```

[image]

(c) Construct numerical solutions by letting `a` run between -1 and 1 with steps of 0.02 in your solutions obtained above. Use `Cases` to choose solutions whenever they are real, and using `ListPlot`, plot all the real solutions occurring in the interval `a\[Element]{-1,1}`.

Ans : no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shortcut a) and b) by using `Eliminate`. You can also ask Mathematica to solve equations over reals. (In v8):

```
In[538]:= eq = 
 Eliminate[3/y^4 == 3/x^4 + a/(x + 2 y)^4 && r == y/x, {x, y}]

Out[538]= -24 r - 72 r^2 - 96 r^3 + (-45 + a) r^4 + 24 r^5 + 72 r^6 + 
  96 r^7 + 48 r^8 == 3

In[539]:= r /. Solve[eq && -1 < a < 1, r, Reals]

Out[539]= {ConditionalExpression[
  Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
     72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 1], -1 < a < 0 || 
   0 < a < Root[-184528125 + 267553125 #1 + 11238750 #1^2 + 
       110250 #1^3 - 225 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1] || 
   Root[-184528125 + 267553125 #1 + 11238750 #1^2 + 110250 #1^3 - 
       225 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1] < a < 1], 
 ConditionalExpression[
  Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
     72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 2], -1 < a < 0 || 
   0 < a < Root[-184528125 + 267553125 #1 + 11238750 #1^2 + 
       110250 #1^3 - 225 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1] || 
   Root[-184528125 + 267553125 #1 + 11238750 #1^2 + 110250 #1^3 - 
       225 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1] < a < 1], 
 ConditionalExpression[
  Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
     72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 3], 
  0 < a < Root[-184528125 + 267553125 #1 + 11238750 #1^2 + 
      110250 #1^3 - 225 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1]], 
 ConditionalExpression[
  Root[-3 - 24 #1 - 72 #1^2 - 96 #1^3 + (-45 + a) #1^4 + 24 #1^5 + 
     72 #1^6 + 96 #1^7 + 48 #1^8 &, 4], 
  0 < a < Root[-184528125 + 267553125 #1 + 11238750 #1^2 + 
      110250 #1^3 - 225 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1]]}
```

You can then plot the resulting solution:

[image]

The `Out[539]` gives you exact algebraic solutions along with conditions when they are real. So the maximum number of real solutions is 4 and occurs when `a` is between zero and `Root[-184528125 + 267553125 #1 + 11238750 #1^2 + 110250 #1^3 - 225 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1]`

Now, let's get to part c). You should use `NSolve` to construct all solutions. Then, as suggested `Cases` to extract real solutions, and then `ListPlot`:

```
Table[Thread[{a, 
    Cases[r /. NSolve[eq, r], r_ /; Im[r] == 0]}], {a, -1, 1, 
   0.02}] // ListPlot
```

[image]